# Is it possible to generically implement the amb operator in D?

Tags: ambiguity, d

Is it possible to generically implement the amb operator in D?

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Amb
http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2005/10/11/amb-operator

The *sort* of thing I'm thinking of is:

```
amb([1, 2]) * amb([3, 4, 5]) == amb([3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10])
amb(["hello", "world"]) ~ amb(["qwerty"]) == amb(["helloqwerty", "worldqwerty"])
amb(["hello", "world"]) ~ "qwerty" == amb(["helloqwerty", "worldqwerty"])
amb(["hello", "very long string"]).length = amb([5, 16])
```

In the last two examples, there really needs to be a 'lifting' of the ~ and .length into the amb 'context' (a monad?).  In the first two examples, the operators should just be applied to the amb's contents.

I've given it a brief try, but I'm having problems when trying to lift the wrapped-type's operators/methods/properties (*, ~ and .length in this example).  How should this be done in D?

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Here's what I came up with.

```
import std.range;
import std.algorithm;
import std.stdio;
import std.functional;
import std.math;
import std.string;

struct AmbRange(R1, R2, alias Op)
{
public:
    this(R1 _r1, R2 _r2) { r1 = _r1; r2 = r2c = _r2; }

    void popFront()
    {
        r2.popFront();
        if (r2.empty) { r2 = r2c; r1.popFront(); }
    }

    @property auto front() { return Op(r1.front, r2.front); }
    @property bool empty() { return r1.empty; }

private:
    R1 r1;
    R2 r2, r2c;
}

struct Amb(R)
{
    alias ElementType!(R) E;

public:
    this(R r) { this.r = r; }

    auto opBinary(string op, T)(T rhs) if (!is(T U : Amb!(U)))
    {
        alias binaryFun!("a"~op~"b") Op;
        return map!((E e) { return Op(e, rhs); })(r);
    }

    auto opBinaryRight(string op, T)(T lhs) if (!is(T U : Amb!(U)))
    {
        alias binaryFun!("a"~op~"b") Op;
        return map!((E e) { return Op(lhs, e); })(r);
    }

    auto opBinary(string op, T)(T rhs) if (is(T U : Amb!(U)))
    {
        alias binaryFun!("a"~op~"b") Op;
        return AmbRange!(R, typeof(rhs.r), Op)(r, rhs.r);
    }

    auto opDispatch(string f, T ...)(T args)
    {
        mixin("return map!((E e) { return e."~f~"(args); })(r);");
    }

    auto opDispatch(string f)()
    {
        mixin("return map!((E e) { return e."~f~"; })(r);");
    }

private:
    R r;
}

auto amb(R)(R r) { return Amb!R(r); }

void main()
{
    auto r1 = 2 * amb([1, 2, 3]);
    assert(equal(r1, [2, 4, 6]));

    auto r2 = amb(["ca", "ra"]) ~ "t";
    assert(equal(r2, ["cat", "rat"]));

    auto r3 = amb(["hello", "cat"]).length;
    assert(equal(r3, [5, 3]));

    auto r4 = amb(["cat", "pat"]).replace("a", "u");
    assert(equal(r4, ["cut", "put"]));

    auto r5 = amb([1, 2]) * amb([1, 2, 3]);
    assert(equal(r5, [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6]));
}
```

Lots of thanks to BCS for figuring out how to resolve the binaryOp ambiguities.

I had to create a new range for traversing the result of a binary op between two `Amb`'s, but I think that works out best anyway.

For those that are new to D, and are curious, all that `string` stuff is done at compile time, so there's no parsing code at runtime or anything like that -- it's pretty much as efficient as hand-coding it in C.

Comment: take a look at using `auto opBinaryRight(string op, T)(T lhs) if(!is(T U : Amb!(U)))`

Comment: Thanks, that's an excellent piece of work, great for illustrating some compile-time features of D.

Would you mind if I took this and extended it with (exception-based?) backtracking as a full amb operator?   (I'll release under MIT/BSD on github, with full credit to you and BCS.)

Comment: Yeah sure, do what you like with it :)  What do you mean by backtracking?

Comment: @chrisdew: if you do, post to the D newsgroup and you might be able to get it into the stdlib.